# Combining Like Terms in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with a very large set of data and I need to quickly combine like terms. The data is broken down into rows that have numbers that represent a store code, and columns that track the day of the week. The data is the amount each store is getting per delivery. [Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OXEp.png) For example, with store 1, I need to combine them all into one row and that number would be 452. One thing to look out for is a store could be getting multiple deliveries a week, up to even 7 deliveries a week. It seems like it should be pretty simple to do, I am just fairly new to excel.
Thanks

Comment: Try using `SUMIFS`, or a pivot table.

Comment: I tried a pivot table an it messes up the data. How would I do it with SUMIFS?

Answer (score 1):

### Sum up Matching Rows

[image]

```
=LET(Data,A2:H20,uh,"Store",vh,"Amount",
    ud,TAKE(Data,,1),vd,DROP(Data,,1),
    u,SORT(UNIQUE(ud)),
    v,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,
        SUM(FILTER(vd,ud=r)))),
VSTACK(HSTACK(uh,vh),HSTACK(u,v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To simplify the formulas I made two Named ranges.
Change SHEET07 in my example with your Sheet name

```
STORECOL=SHEET07!$C$2:$C$17
WEEKTOTALS=SHEET07!$J$2:$J$17
```

**ATTENTION**  CHANGE THE ; IN FORMULAS WITH , (depending on locales of the list separator)

```
Use an array forula in J2 to find unique store Id's.
Paste and press  CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
=IFERROR(INDEX(STORECOL; MATCH(0;COUNTIF($J$1:J1; STORECOL); 0));"")

Use the formula below to sum all weeks sums of the same store:
=SUMIF(STORECOL;J2;WEEKTOTALS)
```